# How to pass value to rootSaga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am now practicing `redux-saga` from [Official Docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html).
And I have a question on the [example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga-beginner-tutorial)

`sagas.js`

```
import {delay} from 'redux-saga';
import {all, call, put, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';

const API_ROOT = 'http://localhost:8000';

const postAPIGetToken = ({username, password}) => {
  const request = axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${API_ROOT}/api-token-auth/`,
    data: {
      username,
      password
    }
  });
  return request();
};


export function* shootAuth(action) {
  const res = yield call(postAPIGetToken, action.payload);
  yield put({
    type: 'GOT_RESPONSE',
    payload: res
  })
}


// single entry point to start all Sagas at once
export default function* rootSaga(values) {
  const {username, password} = values;
  yield all([
    helloSaga(),
    watchIncrementAsync(),
    shootAuth()
  ])
}
```

`main.js`

```
import "babel-polyfill"

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {createStore ,applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import Counter from './Counter'
import reducer from './reducers'
import {helloSaga} from "./sagas";
import rootSaga from "./sagas";
const sagaMiddleWare = createSagaMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleWare)
);
sagaMiddleWare.run(rootSaga);

const action = (type, payload={}) => store.dispatch({type, payload})

function render() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter
      value={store.getState()}
      onIncrement={() => action('INCREMENT')}
      onDecrement={() => action('DECREMENT')}
      onIncrementAsync={() => action('INCREMENT_ASYNC')}
      shootToken={()=>action('SHOOT_TOKEN',
        {
          username: 'tonyod',
          password: 'mbx12345'
        })}
    />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
}

render()
store.subscribe(render)
```

In my working project. I my `react` has `redux-form` and can be able to pass `username/password` already. Here is my method.

```
onSubmit(values) {
    const {username, password} = values;
    this.props.onSubmitClick(values, REQUEST);
  }
```

I have `username` and `password` form. And I would like to pass them to the `saga`. But `rootSaga` has no argument. How can I supply to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `panigrah` from `chat-room/reactjs` gitter.

> you are using sagas to login? Sagas will listen to dispatch method. So in your action handler you dispatch an action like LOGIN with the username and password parameter in the payload. In the saga you can listen for the LOGIN action to be dispatched and get the username and password from the action payload.

Therefore I was going the wrong way of implementation.
I simulate single button will emits an `action` with `type` and `payload` is username and password.

Things I missed are:

1 - I must use `store.dispatch(action)`

```
<Counter
      value={store.getState()}
      shootToken={()=>store.dispatch(
        {
          type:'SHOOT_ASYNC',
          payload: {
            username: 'tonyod',
            password: '12345'
          }
        })
      }
/>
```

2 - I must `takeEvery` or `takeLastest` to watch the `actions` in the app.

```
const postAPIGetToken = (values) => {
  const {username, password} = values;
  return axios.post(`${API_ROOT}/api-token-auth/`,
    {
      username,
      password
    });
};      

export function* shootAuth(action) {
  const res = yield call(postAPIGetToken, action.payload);
  yield put({
    type: 'GOT_RESPONSE',
    payload: res
  })
}   

export function* watchShootAuth() {
  yield takeEvery('SHOOT_ASYNC', shootAuth)
}

// single entry point to start all Sagas at once
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    helloSaga(),
    watchIncrementAsync(),
    watchShootAuth()
  ])
}
```

PS.: `Ctrl + K` does not work on entire No. 2 code. It partially works on them.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass additional parameters to the `sagaMiddleware.run` call, like this:

`sagaMiddleWare.run(rootSaga, value);`

Comment: It have to get value from `redux-dom` which is beyond the scope of this arugment. So I got `ReferenceError value is not defined`.